# Using FME to extract and store data in geodatabase in different feature datasets to create seamless dataset?

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, feature-dataset

Original data structure as supplied is 124 folders with identical feature data sets:

[image: Each folder has 5 shape files]

There is a common attribute in all datasets (metadata) that I need to inspect and extract the data flow for different zones, After manual inspection and extraction, I divided the data in 3 zones (e.g., Z54, Z55 & Z56)

What I want is to extract all features from each folder and place in a feature dataset in a geodatabase as follows:

[image]

where Z54_Grids, Z54_Pages etc. etc. are the containers for features extracted as such from individual folder and Z54_UBD_Data_Combined keeps only one dataset for grids from all folders and Pages, Roads, Suburbs & tiles from all folders.

[image: final structure would be]

Comment: I'm not really sure I know exactly what you're trying to do here.  You want to read all the files from their source folders, then combine them into the appropriate feature datasets in a Geodatabase.  So all the files that are in zone 54 and end in "til" get put into Z54_Tiles feature dataset?  It sounds like this is easily done in FME.  Have you tried anything yet?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: With Fezter here what have you tried? Sound like a dynamic reader is required.

Comment: Hi Fezter, yes I tried a bit already with static and dynamic readers both. It reads and transforms the features in geodatabase as standalone features than putting them into particular feature dataset. Also combining the features it just gives me ObjectID and shape than all attributes. What I am willing to do is (as you understand) read features from all folders belong to Zone 54 and put it specifically into featuredataset named as Z54 and also combine the files as per distinction (grd/til etc.)

Comment: any follow up on this issue ? can't find an optimal workflow (6 years later). Tried feature type dataset fanout but this only allows one feature dataset, at least with one single writer